# On page load, the drawer appears and then slides out of view

Tags: html, themes, drawer, metronic

I am using the metronicv8.2.0 demo20 html theme in my project.
One of the features I have leveraged is the use of metronic drawers.

After adding the required html, if I load the page, the drawer is first displayed and it then slides off the screen.

I am currently trying to figure out how to not display the drawer at all on page load and only display the drawer when the trigger button is clicked upon.  However, I have not been able to figure out how to get this done.

Any help would be appreciated.